# How can I return a list of class attributes in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, class, class-method

I have created a class Students that has 14 attrs.

There are 20 members of the class that has 14 attrs.  One of the attrs is `self.project`. This was initialized under:

```
def __init__(self, name, gender, test1, project, final, midterm.....etc):

    self.name = name
    self.gender = gender
    self.test1 = test1
    self.project = project
    #  .....etc and so on and so forth
```

all 20 members have a project...how can I return a list of the just project entries of all 20 members of my class?

Answer (score 0):

Say, you have a list of instances of your class called `members`. You can iterate over it and extract the `project` attribute with a list comprehension:

```
projects = [mate.project for mate in members]
```

Also, to reduce the initialisation like `self.project = project` in `__init__`, you can use [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

Then your class could look like this:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Member = namedtuple("Member", "name gender test1 project")
class Member(Member):
    def sayHello(self):
        # your own methods can use `self.project` and the like as usual
        print(f'Hello, {self.name}!')
```